# Getting len of large buffered channel blocks for loop

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

I've encountered a strange behaviour. I was playing around with buffered channels, and when using large buffers the whole program execution would block. In the following code snippet:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    choke := make(chan string, 150000)

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 10000000; i++ {
            choke <- string(i)
            fmt.Println("i=", i)
        }
    }()

    for {
        //fmt.Println(len(choke))
        if len(choke) >= 150000 {
            fmt.Println("Full")
        }
    }
}
```

My program blocks at ~96000 iterations and never  reaches the "Full" print, unless I print out `len(choke)` before evaluating it. This is probably due to the delay provided by `fmt.Println`, as the issue can also be "fixed" by adding a small `time.Sleep`.

Could someone explain the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: You have a tight loop there which will use as much CPU as it can. Getting the length of a channel requires locking the channel, so it's constantly locking and unlocking it as fast as it can. You're also checking if it's `>=` the buffer size which implies you think it's somehow possible for its length to exceed its maximum size, which is impossible by definition.

Comment: @Adrian but the question is: Why does printing the length of channel solving the issue?

Comment: Hard to say, you don't show that code.

Comment: @Adrian There's a `fmt.Println(len(choke))` right above `if len(choke) >= 150000`. If you uncomment it, the program will run perfectly and won't block. Wouldn't locking and unlocking the channel with the print only hog the CPU more, and block the program even earlier.

Comment: here's an idiomatic solution to determine if the channel is full without choking goroutines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48939522/checking-channel-length-becomes-unresponsive-in-for-lenc/48939532#48939532

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because your goroutine is never executing. The "for" loop you have outside of the goroutine is a tight loop without any blocking operations, which means it's getting all of the scheduler time. The goroutine you create is therefore never being scheduled to execute.

It works when you have the print statement, because that's a blocking operation (I/O) that causes the Go scheduler to switch to the goroutine you've created.

Comment: But adding a `time.Sleep(1 * time.Millisecond)` instead of the print statement will also make the goroutine execute, and that isn't an I/O operation.

Comment: I edited my comment around the same time you replied. I meant to say "blocking", where the reason it's blocking in this case is because the Print statement is I/O.

Comment: @DavidKomljenovic No, it's not an I/O operation, it's a blocking operation, which also allows the Go runtime to schedule other goroutines.