# Checking channel length becomes unresponsive in `for{ len(c) }`

Tags: go, channel

The following program never prints "Full". With `fmt.Println(len(choke))` uncommented, the program outputs "Full" when the channel is full.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    choke := make(chan string, 150000)

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 10000000; i++ {
            choke <- string(i)
            fmt.Println("i=", i)
        }
    }()

    for {
        //fmt.Println(len(choke))
        if len(choke) >= 150000 {
            fmt.Println("Full")
        }
    }
}
```

@tim-heckman explained the cause of this behavior in [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48791949/getting-len-of-large-buffered-channel-blocks-for-loop).

How do I detect a channel is full without using a hot loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting len of large buffered channel blocks for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48791949/getting-len-of-large-buffered-channel-blocks-for-loop)

Comment: @IvanAracki I originally posted this answer here and it was deleted because that question was too narrow for this answer

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363716/appropriate-to-delete-how-to-fix-answer-to-question-whys-it-broken

Answer (score 3):

Use a `select` statement on the write side. It will write to the channel if there is buffer available or a receiver waiting; it will fallthrough to the `default` case if the channel is full.

```
func main() {
    choke := make(chan string, 150000)
    var i int
    for {
        select {
        case choke <- string(i):
            i++
        default:
            fmt.Println("Full")
            return
        }
    }
}
```